# Battery Bank Replacement

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lithium-polymer, powerbanks

I have an old power bank with swollen battery with the specs you can see in image 1
[image: Case Specs]

This is the module, but I can't find any specs nor schematics on the internet.
The image below will show the full view of power bank module.
[image: Module Full View Front]

This old powerbank using lithium battery but have no marking on it, from dimension I can guess it's 1260110 battery (1.2mm x 60mm x 110mm). I already confirm the voltage is around 3.7
[image: Original Battery Front]

I want to replace the old battery before with this type of battery. I have 6 of this and planning to put them in parallel to get around, 26000mAh.
I get this battery from my old tablet, I already confirm the battery is normal and in good working condition.
[image: Samsung Battery Front]

But this battery originally have 6 pin on it, 2 each colour.
When I test them using voltmeter, any red and any black measured around 3.8v.
But what's weird is then I measure red with yellow it also gives the voltage output put exactly half of the amount if I measure red with black.
Note: measure black with yellow didn't give any voltage at all.
[image: Samsung Battery Connector]

This battery seems to have its own control board (not confirmed). All the information about this Samsung battery specified by 3 picture below.
[image: Samsung Battery Board]
[image: Samsung Battery Catode Anode]
[image: Samsung Battery Serial Number]

So, with all the information above, I have some question:

1. Do I need any modification to the board?
2. If I want to use 6 of the Samsung battery in parallel to get a higher capacity power bank then connect it to the power bank module, do I need to remove the protection circuit on each battery and connect the + - directly from battery to module (without board in img.9)? Or it's safer to just connect the red and black (img.8) to the board without any modification?
3. Do I need BMS to make sure all 6 battery in the same level?
4. I'm planning to add temp sensor using thermistor (cut off at 60 Celsius) to make it safer to use, but is it really necessary?

Thank you for reading and responding to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this by saying I do not recommend messing around with lithium ion or lithium polymer batteries. That being said:

At 3.8V the samsung battery you have is most certainly 1s, the half voltage might be created with a voltage divider?

1
anyways, take off any and all circuitry from your samsung battery and attach it to the circuit. HOWEVER!! first be sure to check Rvset on that IP5328, found here: [IP5328 datasheet](http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/ec29931791194a51119ee1d6a4a21efb.pdf) (page 6) If you can find no such resistor It will charge up to 4.24V which is ok for the samsung cell. If there is a resistor it will overcharge your cell and the consequences could be extremely dangerous. Also please check if it has undervoltage protection, hook up a bench power supply instead of a battery, and it should switch off at approximately 3.1V.

2 + 3
batteries can be hooked up in parallel without a BMS as they will self-balance, DO BE SURE to have them all as close to eachother as possible in terms of voltage, within 0.2V is ok. You can remove the circuitry as it will likely not do anything, and your IP5328 has protections built in.

4
A temperature sensor is always nice, but not necessary. Also have it cut-off around 40 degrees instead as any higher can damage cells.

One last thing, all 6 cells have to be at an acceptable capacity, otherwise all others will rapidly lose capacity until they're all approximately the same.

Comment: The numbered list (if that is what it is) doesn't seem to be formatted correctly.